# Array of Buttons in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I tried to make an array of buttons:

```
Button[] buttonlist = new Button[2];

Button btn1;
Button btn2;
Button btn3;
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

buttonlist[0] = btn1;
buttonlist[1] = btn2;
buttonlist[2] = btn3;
```

What did I do wrong here ? 
Thanks !

Comment: The way you use it defeats the point of storing them into an array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Must be `Button[] buttonlist = new Button[3];`

Comment: I thought counting of arrays starts at 0 ?

Comment: Yes, but you have 3 buttons, not 2. When defining array you specify its size therefore 3. And having declared it you have button[0], [1] and [2]

Answer (score 1):

Array index in java doesnt start with 1...It starts with 0...This was the mistake you have done..
you must remove this line

```
buttonlist[2] = btn3;
```

or add this line

```
Button[] buttonlist = new Button[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out.Hope it works :)

```
Button btn[] = new Button[2];
for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
    btn[i] = new Button(this); // initialize it
    btn[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btn[i].setText(name[i]);
    layout.addView(btn[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is fully right, but I just wanted to add that you could avoid using temporary variables and directly assign your button in your array:

```
Button[] buttonlist = new Button[3];

buttonlist[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
buttonlist[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
buttonlist[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

In my opinion, that's more readable ;)